# Is there a way to monitor a local variable on a running real time software, other than copying it to a memory location or defining it as a static?

Tags: c, optimization, real-time, simulink, execution-time

Example:

```
int Global;

void outputFunction(void) {
    int local1;
    int local2;
    local1 = 10;
    local2 = 5 + local1;
    Global = local2;
}
```

in the previous example `local1` and `local2` are not in scope.
am working with real time software (generated from simulink-coder) and i need to find a way to use the signals(1 up to 5 thousand) as locals so that i can benefit from the high execution or turnaround time, but at the same time i need to access any signal at anytime while the code is being executed.
i thought about overwriting on run time if i added a label and  nops after the each local variable assignment. and during runtime finding a way to overwrite those nops to mov the register to a scoped register like %%xmm7.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is, no, unless you have a socket'ed processor with a high end debugger/data logger that allows full access to all registers and memory.  This is likely going to be expensive ~$10k at least and is of marginal value if your application must live in a harsh environment.  If this is generated code, I highly recommend **against** editing it after code gen.  This can lead to all kinds of *fun* later when you try to recreate a previous build, unless you are extremely disciplined about development, which is rare in research and development.  :-)

Comment: Actually i found a way, but it is quite complicated. the code can be edited by a label after each local variable assignment. like 
localVariable = 10;
__asm__ __volatile__ ("L_localVariable:");
__asm__ __volatile__ (".global L_localVariable");
then you can disassemble the code, then write a script to check at this label the assigned register and the number of bytes after that label.
write a function to overwrite the number of bytes after the label with a jump to a function and inside this function you can copy that register to a memory location (Global Variable)
then you can watch it ;-)